# vb.net return age from dob and if under 18 show hidden fields?

Tags: javascript, function

I am having problems with writing code behind for showing hidden fields if a user is under 18. This is the code im using to calculate the age.

```
       function getAge(dateString) {
            var today = new Date();
            var birthDate = new Date(Date.parse(dateString.value, "MM/dd/yyyy"));
            var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
            var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
            if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
                age--;
            }
            document.getElementById("lblage").innerHTML = age;
        }
```

To sum up what i want help with is , how can I validate my .vb code so that hidden fields will appear on click once a user has typed an age that is under 18

thanks :)

Comment: You've mentioned *four* different languages in the tags. Which do you *really* want the code in?

Comment: "I am having problems" isn't very specific.  How are you calling this method?  What value are you passing it?  How is it failing?  What specifically is going wrong?

Comment: @Steve There's a 5 tag limit.  I'm sure that would have been the 6th if it were allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply check

```
if(age<18){
   forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("justforkids"),function(el){
       el.style.display="block";
   });
}
```